# UIToolBar images are displaying incorrectly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

I have a problem with this UIToolBar displaying images incorrectly. Some show fine and others don't. I was wondering if anyone has encountererd this before. Not sure if it's a transparency thing perhaps. You can see how image 1 and image 3 are white circles when actually they are png icon images.

thanks for any help

Here's the image I'm trying to show:

[image]

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you make the images yourself? Did you make the settings Icon? Trying to get a little more info about how you came across these icons.

Comment: they were provided by a client. the gear image that is working is from glyph icons. thanks :)

Comment: When you do a "Get Info" on the one that isn't working, does it have an Alpha Channel in the "More Info" section?

Comment: @jhilgert00 Get Info shows Alpha channel: Yes

Comment: hmmm. Well, I would at least try to open one in Photoshop, and resave as a png-24 with transparency using File > Save for Web & Devices. Maybe there's something other than the alpha channel that's quirky.

Comment: @jhilgert00 I tried your suggestion but still the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab bar icons are just template images, so iOS renders the effects itself. You have to to add an image without any effects and colors to make it work properly. Check out the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW8) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW52). In your example it may be a singlecolored circle with cutouts for the "az".